# 'int' object is not subscriptable after if statement

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'score': [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]})
```

And I want to create a new column based on the conditions in the 'score' column.

I tried it out like this

```
df['happiness'] = df['score']
def are_you_ok(df):
    if df['happiness'] >= 4:
        return 'happy',
    elif df['happiness'] <= 2:
        return 'sad',
    else:
        return 'ok'

df['happines'] = df['happiness'].apply(are_you_ok)
df
```

When I try to run that though, all I get is:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Can I not use this kind of function with an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) from `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

conds = [df.score >=4, df.score <=2]

choices = ['happy', 'sad']

df['happiness'] = np.select(conds, choices, default='ok')

>>> df
    name  score happiness
0  Jason      1       sad
1  Molly      3        ok
2   Tina      4     happy
3   Jake      5     happy
4    Amy      2       sad
```

Note: you can avoid explicitly importing `numpy` by using `pandas.np` (or `pd.np`, depending how you imported pandas) instead of just `np`

Answer (score 1):

Using [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

```
pd.cut(df.score,[0,2,4,np.Inf],labels=['sad','ok','happy'])
Out[594]: 
0      sad
1       ok
2       ok
3    happy
4      sad

#df['yourcol']=pd.cut(df.score,[0,2,4,np.Inf],labels=['sad','ok','happy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `apply` applies your function to every single value in the column. `df` is not a `DataFrame` inside of `are_you_ok`, but (in your case) an integer. Naturally, Python is complaining that you cannot index into integers with `['happiness']`.

Your code is quite easy to fix, though. Just rewrite `are_you_ok` such that it works with integer arguments.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
   ...:         'score': [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]})
   ...:         
In [3]: def are_you_ok(x):
   ...:     if x >= 4:
   ...:         return 'happy'
   ...:     elif x <= 2:
   ...:         return 'sad'
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return 'ok'
   ...:     
In [4]: df['happiness'] = df['score'].apply(are_you_ok)
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
    name  score happiness
0  Jason      1       sad
1  Molly      3        ok
2   Tina      4     happy
3   Jake      5     happy
4    Amy      2       sad
```